# nodejs passport authentication with Rational Team Concert

Tags: node.js, oauth, rtc

I was trying to authenticate to RTC using passport. My code is as given below:

```
*var  config        = require('./public/scripts/oauthconfig.js')
var  passport      = require('passport');
var  https         = require('https');
var  OAuthStrategy = require('passport-oauth').OAuthStrategy;
var  cookieParser  = require('cookie-parser');
var  cookieSession = require('cookie-session');
passport.use('jazz', new OAuthStrategy({
        requestTokenURL:      config.rtc.requestTokenURL,
        accessTokenURL:       config.rtc.accessTokenURL,
        userAuthorizationURL: config.rtc.userAuthorizationURL,
        consumerKey:          config.rtc.consumerKey,
        consumerSecret:       config.rtc.consumerSecret,
        callbackURL:          config.rtc.callbackURL
    },
    function(token, tokenSecret, profile, done) {
        return done(null, profile);
    }
));

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    console.log('serializeUser: ' + user._id)
    done(null, user._id);
});

console.log("Starting in Test Mode:4");
passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    done(null, id);
});

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(cookieSession({ secret: 'secret', cookie: { maxAge: new Date(Date.now() + 3600000), }}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session({"secret":"secret"}));
app.get('/', function(request, response) {
    response.render('index', {
        user: request.user
    });
});

app.get('/auth/jazz', passport.authenticate('jazz'));
app.get('/auth/jazz/callback',
    passport.authenticate('jazz', {successRedirect: '/', failureRedirect: '/auth/jazz' }));
The config is specified as below:
var cfg = {
    rtc: {
        requestTokenURL:      '[rtc_server]:9443/jts/oauth-request-token',
        accessTokenURL:       '[rtc_server]:9443/jts/oauth-access-token',
        userAuthorizationURL: '[rtc_server]:9443/jts/oauth-authorize',
        consumerKey:          '5818a222233333333344444444472c62c5',
        consumerSecret:       'secret',
        callbackURL:          '[rtc_server]:9443/auth/jazz/callback',
        host:                 '[rtc_server]',
        port:                 '9443'
    }
}*
```

Now when I invoke an xhrGet on /auth/jazz, I expect the browser to authenticate using the consumerKey and secret. But the request is timed out after waiting for more than 1 minute..

Since I am new to this, I could not figure out the actual issue. I am also getting this message in the logs:

err InternalOAuthError: Failed to obtain request token
err at emitErrorNT (net.js:1256:8)
err at OAuthStrategy._createOAuthError (/home/vcap/app/node_modules/passport- oauth/node_modules/passport-oauth1/lib/strategy.js:396:17)

err at /home/vcap/app/node_modules/passport-oauth/node_modules/passport-oauth1/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth.js:543:17

err at ClientRequest. (/home/vcap/app/node_modules/passport-oauth/node_modules/passport-oauth1/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth.js:421:9)